# ValueError: TensorFlow requires that the following symbols must be defined before the loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create an input pipeline using the [tf.data API.](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) I have 3D data and using normal NumPy operations I would've ended up with an array with dimensions [?,256x256x3x100], which one can think of as 100 frames each of 256x256x3 size.

```
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

def readfile(filenames):
    flag = 0
    for name in filenames:
        string = tf.read_file(name)
        image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
        if flag == 0:
            bunch = image
            flag = 1
        else:
            bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)   
    return bunch

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    train_files = []
    for s in [x[0] for x in os.walk("path/to/data/folders")]:
        if(s == "path/to/data/folders"):
            continue
        train_files.append(glob.glob(s+"/*.png"))
    # shape of train_files is [5,100]
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(readfile, num_parallel_calls=16)
```

I think the error is occurring because 'bunch' is changing size in for loop. Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-c2f88ca344dc> in <module>
      22     train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
 ---> 23             readfile, num_parallel_calls=16)


ValueError: in converted code:

ValueError: TensorFlow requires that the following symbols must be defined before the loop: ('bunch',)
```

How do I read the data correctly?

**EDIT**

What worked for me:

```
def readfile(filenames):
    flag = 0
    name = filenames[0]
    string = tf.read_file(name)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
    bunch = image
    for name in filenames:
        string = tf.read_file(name)
        image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
        if flag == 0:
            bunch = image
            flag = 1
        else:
            bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)   
    return bunch
```

So I'm not sure why it is necessary to initialise `bunch` before the loop, when the first iteration should take care of that `bunch = image`. It might be because flag is not defined as a tensor so `bunch = image` is never actually run?

Comment: the problem here is with the `bunch` variable. You have never declared it and use it in `bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)`. At the beginning of the `readfile` function, declare `bunch=[]` (or whatever type matches)

Comment: @learner in the first iteration, `bunch = image`, why isn't that equivalent to declaring it? I tried  declaring `bunch=[]` but that was giving shape errors. So I just read the first image frame outside the for loop and assigned it to `bunch` and ran again, this time no errors!

Comment: Exactly, the variable`bunch` needs to be declared outside the loop. When you call a function through `map`, no variables must be declared within the function, because a graph is created before the session runs and once the graph is created you can't add additional variables. It was my mistake to ask you to declare it inside the function, I meant as a global variable in my comment. Also if acceptable, I'll put down as an answer, so that you can mark accepted

Comment: @learner sure! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `bunch` is created inside the function `readfile()` and therefore the error, because variables cannot be created inside the loop at run time. A fix would be to move the declaration of the variable `bunch` outside the loop. Code sample follows:

```
import glob
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

def readfile(filenames):
    flag = 0
    bunch = <some_appropriate_initialization>
    for name in filenames:
        string = tf.read_file(name)
        image = tf.image.decode_image(string, channels=3)
        if flag == 0:
            bunch = image
            flag = 1
        else:
            bunch = tf.concat([bunch,image],1)   
    return bunch

# Rest of the code
```

Comment: just to make it clear, what worked for me was to do the initialisation outside of the loop, within the function. So possibly creating `bunch` inside the function isn't the problem, though I'm not sure. It might be because `flag` is not defined as a tensor so `bunch = image` is never actually run. I will check and update.

Comment: I tried making everything a tensor, including using `tf.cond` but it still gives the same error. The only thing that works is having `bunch` initialised outside of the loop, but inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use arbitrary python code inside a `dataset.map` function, that is `readfile` in your case. There are two ways to solve this:

1. By using `readfile` code as it is and by calling it as`tf.py_function` instead, here you can do eager execution, hence you can write any python logic as normal.
2. By converting the code in `readfile` and making use of only tensorflow functions to do the transformation. Performance-wise this is much better than using `tf.py_function`.

You can find an example on both at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function

Comment: thanks, I tried coding everything inside the function using only TensorFlow but it still gives the same error. I will try using `tf.py_function`. You can see my update, it seems to work but I have no idea why.